# changing the condition for a loop after a maximum value is reached for the first time

Tags: matlab, loops

I need my simulation to switch from charging to discharging mode once a maximum temperature value is reached for the first time.

My Matlab code has a series of if loops, and the condition (w = 1 or w = 2) for these if statements is time-dependent. I read in a defined schedule where it looks at a charge/discharge cycle over 24 hours and the condition is defined once per hour.

I have been able to shift from charging to discharging, where the charging cycle kicks back in once the temperature drops below the defined maximum. However, I dont want charging to occur for the rest of the 24 hour cycle after the temperature has reached its defined maximum for the first time.

Is there any solution to this, possibly some loop that contains an "until" function?

```
for ii = 1:M-1

             if w == 1

                    Temp(ii) = Temp(ii-1)+X; 

             elseif w == 2

                    Temp(ii) = Temp(ii-1)-Y;

             end

end
```

Comment: Where is the `w` condition set in your code? Can you not just change it back to `2` once the maximum temperature is reached?

Comment: What is the intended behaviour? Change until a temperature is reached? Charge until a defined charging time is reached?

Comment: The w is defined on an excel spreadsheet that is read in using an xlsread command. The time step I use is 1 minute, and the w can be changed on the hour so therefore there is one w value for 60 timesteps.

Comment: @Daniel - It is to change once a defined charging time is reached. However, if the temperature reaches above a certain level, I want w to change from charging mode to a discharge mode. The max temperature may not necessarily be reached, this only occurs if the charging time is long enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a variable to store that you have reached the maximum temperature during the current 24-hour period:

```
temperatureMax = getTemperatureMax();
for day = startDay:endDay
   temperatureMaxReached = false;
   for hour = 0:23
      if temperatureMaxReached
         discharge();
      else
         temperature = getTemperature(day, hour);
         if temperature > temperatureMax
            temperatureMaxReached = true;
            discharge();
         else
            charge();
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Could I just define temperatureMax = 100 rather than getTemperatureMax()? Also, is the "Reached" term you use, i.e. temperatureMaxReached, already built into Matlab or do I need to define it elsewhere? Finally, would temperature have an index on it, eg temperature(ii) or not?

Comment: **1.** "Could I just define temperatureMax = 100 rather than getTemperatureMax()?" Sure. With this getTemperatureMax function I just wanted to say "get max. temperature from somewhere". You can use a constant, call a function, calculate it locally etc.

Comment: **2.** "Also, is the "Reached" term you use, i.e. temperatureMaxReached, already built into Matlab or do I need to define it elsewhere?" This variable is a logical (Boolean) variable I define locally. Its name refers to its meaning: if its value is true, it means that the maximum has already been reached; if its value is false, it means the maximum has not been reached yet.

Comment: When the simulation of a day starts, I set its value to false. When the simulation of an hour of a given day starts, I check its value: if it's true, I discharge. If it's false, I check whether the current temperature exceeds the allowed maximum value. If yes, then I store this fact for the rest of the simulated day by setting temperatureMaxReached to true, and discharge. If no, I charge.

Comment: **3.** "Finally, would temperature have an index on it, eg temperature(ii) or not?" Sure, you can use a matrix to store temperature values and get the current value by indexing. When I wrote getTemperature(day, hour), I meant "get the temperature for the currently simulated hour of the currently simulated day".